# Is there any Ruby web app/gem which offsers a web shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-admin

Is there any Ruby web app/ gem which allows you to administrate a computer ( I'm mostly interested in running shell commands ) through a web interface?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of projects on GitHub, might want to look at them. Personally, I have never tried them, so cannot recommend one in particular.

Also, would it possible just to capture the command and run the [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005971) method?